# Find a closed form for the generating function for each sequence below

Tags: combinatorics

I understand the generating function of this sequence. But I'm not sure how to put this in the closed form.

(1) -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0

(2) 0,0,3,-3,3,-3,3,-3

(3) 1,0,1,0,1,0

(4) $a_n = 4-7n$ for all $n \geq 0$

For the first one I think it is $-\dfrac{1-x^8}{1-x}$.
by doing $-(1+x+x^2...)$.

For the second is it just an index shift? But what's the alternating one? i'm not sure.

Comment: Are these finite or infinite? (1) seems right to me...

Answer (score 0):

Hint for (3): Think of
$$
\frac{1}{1-x^2}
$$
as a geometric series with ratio $x^2$.

Hint for (4): you should be familiar with series that resemble
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n
$$
from calculus.

Comment: doesn't really help me :(

Comment: Surely you know the series representation of $1/(1-x)$?

Answer (score 0):

(2) looks like
$$
3x^2 - 3x^3 + 3x^4 \pm = 3x^2(1-x+x^2\pm)
$$
and you have a geometric series with a negative factor...

(3) seems like
$$
1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + \ldots = 1 + (x^2)^1 + (x^2)^2 + (x^2)^3
$$

(4) is direct
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (4-7n) x^n
  = 4 \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n - 7 \sum_{n=0}^\infty  n x^n
$$
where the first one is a geometric series, and the second one is the derivative of the geometric series...